# What is the appropriate use of "lighted" vs "lit"?

Tags: word-choice

Is it acceptable to say "her eyes lighted up" or is it only acceptable to say "her eyes lit up"?

Comment: You can use either. Most people where I'm from would use *lit* but *lighted* is certainly acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

This [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=eyes+lighted+up%2Ceyes+lit+up&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ceyes%20lighted%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceyes%20lit%20up%3B%2Cc0) suggests that `eyes lighted up` lost ground to `eyes lit up` in the early 1900s

[image]

Also worth noting that [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/light) no longer lists `lighted` as the past simple form of `light`. It just lists `lit`

[image]

I would say that `lighted up` sounds a bit archaic today and you should go with `lit up`.

Comment: NGrams prove nothing. A lot of the "lit up" you'll find there has nothing to do with eyes lighting up. In fact, "lit up" is gaining currency as meaning "fired upon" as in a battle.

Comment: @Robusto: Disagree. See edit.

Comment: So what is your point, then? That a writer should only prefer phrases that are more frequently encountered? What a boring language we would have if that were true.

Comment: No, my point is that I edited the ngram from "lighted up vs lit up" to "eyes lighted up vs eyes lit up". "lit up" still wins. I'm quoting facts, not commenting on the best writing practices because this isn't the place for that.

Comment: I'm talking about the answer as a whole. Your edit is included in my assessment. And this *is* the place for talking about practices, because that is what the OP is asking about. "Is it acceptable to say 'her eyes lighted up?'" Your answer seems calculated to answer that question in the negative.

Comment: @Robusto: As an avid reader, I couldn't agree with you more. However, the OP clearly states if it's _acceptable_ to _"say it"_ (I'm assuming in everyday speech). So, I was trying to point out that saying it might be considered archaic.

Comment: What to you sounds archaic may to another sound merely more formal, more reserved, or more evocative of something you cannot comprehend out of context. Your graph and the single dictionary citation (I can find other dictionaries that *do* list "lighted" as alternative past tenses—some even as the primary citation—seem like an over-zealous attempt to prove something that is ultimately not true. In any case, what does it matter? This question was closed as a duplicate anyway.

Comment: Note that the down vote was not mine. Just wanted to get that on the record.